# On windows 10, How Can I See All Attempts to Open/Read a File

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I have an app that crashes sometimes. The only error message I get is this:

```
Windows cannot access the file  for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program App because of this error.

Program: App
File:

The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
- It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted.
- It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C00000C4
```

The error message is saying that a file could not be "accessed". But it doesn't tell me which file. Is there a way on windows 10 to see every single attempted file access? That way, I can determine which file the app was trying to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sysinternals has a tool named [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) for exactly this.

However, 0xC00000C4 seems to be commonly associated with disk I/O errors, so if the file is local, the Event Log Viewer (eventvwr.msc) should also tell you about all failed disk reads in the 'System' log.